# Match everything after char occurs 5 times and before 6th

Tags: java, regex

i would like to get

```
847F56B42427DCCD3CB311F905BBEF2097F3AA5F
```

from

```
"ImageURL": "http://cloud-3.steamusercontent.com/ugc/929312733724516985/847F56B42427DCCD3CB311F905BBEF2097F3AA5F/",
```

i allready found the regex for this

```
(?<=\/ugc\/.*?\/)(.*.)(?=(\/"))
```

But Java doesn't accept the "*" in the lookbehind and i struggle to find another solution.
The url is always the same, only the numbers after ".../ugc/" are changing.

Comment: If that's JSON, you should parse the JSON first instead

Comment: No need of a lookbehind, use a capturing group and acess it upon a valid match (something like `matcher.group(1)`).

Comment: A good idea!
At the moment i solved it with a bigger regex and then split the match by "/", will try the capturing group

Comment: *Unrelated:* You do know that `.*.` is a weird way of writing `.+`, right?